# Even Piecewise Function

Tags: calculus

Given that

$$
f(x) = 
\begin{cases}
x^3 & \text{if $x \geq 0$}\\
x & \text{if $x < 0$}
\end{cases}
$$

which of the following functions is even?

I. $f(x)$

II. $f(|x|)$

III. $|f(x)|$

I believe I have shown I. is not even and that II. is even. From what I can tell III. seems to be even as well but the answer is showing that it's just II that's even. Here's what I've done for III.

III. First, I defined $|f(x)|$ first to be $|-x^3| = x^3$ when $x \geq 0$ and $|-x| = x$ when $x < 0$.

Then to determine if it's even, for $x \geq 0$, $|f(-x)| = |(-x)^3| = |-x^3| = x^3 = |f(x)|$. Also, $|f(-x)| = |-x| = x$ when $x < 0$.

Can someone please point out the flaw in my thinking?

Comment: No, when $x > 0$, $f(-x)$ is not $(-x)^3$. To spot-check for evenness, try a few input values.

Comment: Hello, welcome MathSE! Thank you so much for the thoroughness of your question and your excellent demonstration of [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). Here’s a [MathJax guide](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to help you compose visually stellar posts.

Comment: PS: using MathJax is a requirement.

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.